# Proving $\dim A<\dim B$ and $\dim C=\dim B$ iff $A\subset B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let A, B be spans:
$$ A=\operatorname{span}(u_1,...,u_n)$$
$$ B=\operatorname{span}(v_1,...,v_m)$$
$$ C=\operatorname{span}(v_1,...,v_m,u_1,...,u_n)$$
I have an exercise in which I need to check for a lot of different sets like these if $A\subset B$, $B\subset A$ or $A=B$. I thought about a statement which intuitively makes sense and will help me solve this exercise:
$$(\dim A<\dim B)\land  (\dim C=\dim B) \iff A \subset B $$
I am unable to prove this statement, can someone help?

Comment: The union of two subspaces is not a subspace, unless one of them is contained in the other.

Comment: oh, i see my mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Consider the short exact sequence
\begin{alignat}{3}
0\longrightarrow A\cap B&\longrightarrow &A\times B&\longrightarrow{}& C\longrightarrow 0 \\
x&\longmapsto &(x,x) &\\
&&(u,v)&\longmapsto &\hskip-3.5em u-v
\end{alignat}
which implies $\;\dim A+\dim B=\dim(A\times B)=\dim(A\cap B)+\dim C$. What can you deduce from the hypothesis on dimensions?

Comment: I'm not familliar with this term and notation, can you expound?

Comment: It means the map with domain $A\cap B$ is injective, the map with codomain $C$ is surjective, and the kernel of this map is exactly the image of the former map.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the definition that $A\subseteq C$, $B\subseteq C$ and $A+B=C$.

By Grassmann's formula, $\dim C=\dim(A+B)=\dim A+\dim B-\dim(A\cap B)$.

($\Rightarrow$) The condition that $\dim C=\dim B$ forces $B=C$ and $\dim A=\dim(A\cap B)$. Since $A\cap B\subseteq A$, this forces $A\cap B=A$, that is, $A\subseteq B$. Together with $\dim A<\dim B$, we obtain $A\subsetneq B$.

($\Leftarrow$) Conversely, assume $A\subsetneq B$. Then $\dim A<\dim B$; moreover
$$
\dim C=\dim(A+B)=\dim A+\dim B-\dim(A\cap B)=\dim A+\dim B-\dim A=\dim B
$$